# Firebase dynamic link - opening multiple instance of the app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm using Firebase dynamic link for deferred deeplinking following the guidelines mentioned in firebase docs.
I'm facing a weird issue, if I open the link in WhatsApp or SMS app, the application opens in whatsapp or sms while there is already an instance of the deeplinked app running. 
Is there any solution for this?[image]

Comment: Did you ever solve it?

Comment: Did you solve it??

Comment: Same problem for me in android emulator but not iOS real device. Did you solve it?

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 13):

If you are using multiple activities then 
            `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` seems to work .

```
 <activity
        android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"/>
```

But in my case I am using single activity architecture , not sure how to handle it .

Comment: Getting this error on build: Manifest merger failed : Attribute activity#com.app.app.MainActivity@launchMode value=(singleTop) from AndroidManifest.xml:19:13-48
   is also present at AndroidManifest.xml:19:13-48 value=(singleInstance).

Comment: Check merged manifest if any errror

Comment: I was opening my flutter app via share extension, I was stuck on the same issue, android:launchMode="singleInstance" worked, 
thanks mate, you saved my couple of hours